# Creating VIJAVA ServiceInstance using VIM UserSessionService without using username,password again

Tags: java, vsphere

I am new to VIJAVA and vwc plugin development. I have successfully got the userSession from current VWC UserSessionService. Now I can get username, sessioninfo, serverinfo from this object.

Now i want to create new ServiceInstance object in vijava WITHOUT entering user credentials again as mentioned below.

```
ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL(

"_https://10.x.x.x/sdk"), "administrator@vsphere.local",

"Password", true);
```

I DONT WANT TO USE THE ABOVE AND I WANT TO USE THE BELOW OVERLOADING. Or somehow i need to create ServiceInstance using UserSessionService object.

```
    ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(url, sessionStr, ignoreCert) 
or something equivalent
```

Kindly helpe me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to grab the session first. Im not sure what you are talking about when you say:

> I have successfully got the userSession from current VWC UserSessionService

But if you have the session it is something that looks like:

> vmware_soap_session="B3240D15-34DF-4BB8-B902-A844FDF42E85"

To make a ServiceInstance from that you use something like this:

```
ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL("https://vcenter/sdk"), sessionString, true);
```

This will use the constructor in ServiceInstance that takes a URL, a sessionString, and says to ignore ssl certs.

I would suggest moving to [YAVIJAVA](https://github.com/yavijava/yavijava) if only for logging.